# Laravel 5.4 Middleware issue

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

When ever i try to route through a middleware it gives me Internal server error. status 500.
I don't seem to understand what is causing this behavior.

Bellow is my code

### kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyJWTToken::class,

];
```

### web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () 
{
    Route::get('guser', 'UserController@getUser');

});
```

### VerifyJWTToken

```
 class VerifyJWTToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       /* try
        {
            $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->input('token'));
        }
        catch (JWTException $e) 
        {
            if($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException) 
            {
                return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException) 
            {
                return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
            }else
            {
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Token is required']);
            }
        }*/
       return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: your middleware php file is not minimal nor complete, please remove the comments and add lines before the middleware class definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass an **array of middleware** in  **Route::group** not a **string**.
Just check [5.4/middleware#registering-middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware)

Do like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function () 
{
    Route::get('guser', 'UserController@getUser');

});
```

Comment: Still the same internal server error. I have tried different ways of declaring middlewares thats not the issue.